# Why does this member function behave differently when defined in a header file?

Tags: c++, class, unreal-engine4

I had been using a header file to contain a class's entire definition just for throwing things together.

The function in question is **`GetLocalCentroidOnShell()`**; a public member of the class `Cell`. Like everything else in the class, I wrote its definition in Cell.h.

I discovered that if I called `GetLocalCentroidOnShell()` from some other member function in the same class, it behaved properly. But if I instead called `GetLocalCentroidOnShell()` through a different class's object, it would return incorrect values.

This is a simple test:

```
void APlanetOfCells::TestCentroidLocations() const
{
    for (int32 i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Cell %d:"), i);

        // Call GetLocalCentroidOnShell() from right here
        FVector centroid = Cells[i].GetLocalCentroidOnShell();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Planet object says centroid is --> %s."), *centroid.ToString());

        // Call GetLocalCentroidOnShell() from inside the cell object instead
        Cells[i].PrintCentroid();
    }
}
```

... where `PrintCentroid` is also a `Cell` member function, simply doing the same thing as the test's code:

```
void Cell::PrintCentroid() const
{
    FVector centroid = GetLocalCentroidOnShell();
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Cell object says centroid is ----> %s."), *centroid.ToString());
}
```

Results:

```
LogTemp: Cell 0:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=16.683 Y=75.035 Z=63.190.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=16.683 Y=75.035 Z=63.190.
LogTemp: Cell 1:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=-49.525 Y=114.088 Z=126.379.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=-66.207 Y=39.053 Z=63.190.
LogTemp: Cell 2:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=48.347 Y=128.999 Z=117.164.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=97.871 Y=14.911 Z=-9.215.
LogTemp: Cell 3:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=122.630 Y=185.318 Z=82.356.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=74.284 Y=56.319 Z=-34.807.
LogTemp: Cell 4:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=210.574 Y=213.893 Z=45.813.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=87.944 Y=28.575 Z=-36.543.
```

The Planet and Cell lines in each pair should be identical.

The fix was to move the definition of **`GetLocalCentroidOnShell()`** out of the header file and into a source file. So instead of this in Cell.h (which returns wrong values):

```
FVector GetLocalCentroidOnShell() const
{
    FVector sum = FVector();

    for (int32 edge = 0; edge < ShellEdgesWithNeighbours.Num(); ++edge)
    {
        sum += ShellEdgesWithNeighbours[edge].EdgeStartPosition;
    }

    return sum / static_cast<float>(ShellEdgesWithNeighbours.Num());
}
```

... I have this in Cell.cpp (which is a straight Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, and returns correct values):

```
FVector Cell::GetLocalCentroidOnShell() const
{
    FVector sum = FVector();

    for (int32 edge = 0; edge < ShellEdgesWithNeighbours.Num(); ++edge)
    {
        sum += ShellEdgesWithNeighbours[edge].EdgeStartPosition;
    }

    return sum / static_cast<float>(ShellEdgesWithNeighbours.Num());
}
```

Results:

```
LogTemp: Cell 0:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=6.923 Y=65.276 Z=53.430.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=6.923 Y=65.276 Z=53.430.
LogTemp: Cell 1:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=-66.207 Y=39.053 Z=63.190.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=-66.207 Y=39.053 Z=63.190.
LogTemp: Cell 2:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=97.871 Y=14.911 Z=-9.215.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=97.871 Y=14.911 Z=-9.215.
LogTemp: Cell 3:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=74.284 Y=56.319 Z=-34.807.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=74.284 Y=56.319 Z=-34.807.
LogTemp: Cell 4:
LogTemp: Warning: Planet object says centroid is --> X=87.944 Y=28.575 Z=-36.543.
LogTemp: Warning: Cell object says centroid is ----> X=87.944 Y=28.575 Z=-36.543.
```

#### The question:

Why does defining **`GetLocalCentroidOnShell()`** in the header file lead to different behaviour?

I do not know if this is a C++ thing, a compiler thing, an Unreal thing, or perhaps something else.

Using VS2017 & UE 4.25.

Comment: Where is `ShellEdgesWithNeighbours` defined?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and show a [mre] that everyone else in the world can cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** compile, run, and reproduce your observed results. Until you do that, it's unlikely that anyne will be able to tell you much. There could be many reasons for undefined behaviorin C++. Only a [mre] can authoritatively determine the reason.

Comment: @BillLynch ShellEdgesWithNeighbours is an array defined in the same class's constructor (also in the same header). It is an array of type ShellEdgesWithNeighbour, a struct declared in the same header, preceding the class definition.

Comment: My guess would be an ODR violation somewhere

Comment: Is there any free function named GetLocalCentroidOnShell?

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. The question was actually intended to ask if the behaviour described is a normal thing that I hadn't learnt yet, rather than ask for help debugging something I already knew to be a bug (as I didn't already know). Admittedly, the way I presented it could have been clearer on that difference.

However the responses since have been implicitly suggesting the kind of answer I was after: *Nope, this behaviour is typically a bug in the code.* The example above is resolved as described, but if I do debug & learn its root cause I'll update the OP for interest's sake. Ty :)

Comment: It is not possible to create a minimal reproducible example as the reproduction of this behavior implies the use of the linker. There is enough information in here to know what happens.